# Tkinter not allowing keyboard input after exiting in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, i3

I'm having an issue with the keyboard not working after exiting a tkinter application written in Jupyter notebooks. If I run this code and exit the program with a kill command(via i3) then the issue doesn't happen. However, if I exit with the exit button, I'm unable to use my keyboard until I use the keyboard in another window first. While in the current jupyter tab it won't work.

I thought it was an issue with the root.mainloop() running in the background, but I'm not sure that is it.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import os, sys

# setting the main application window
root = Tk()
root.title("Select Cases")

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set(int(0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass
def exit():
    #root.unbind("<Return>")
    for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
        child.destroy()
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()
    raise SystemExit

# creating a content frame
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# creating the Entry Widget
feet = StringVar()
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W,E))

# remaining widgets
meters = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=W)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Exit", command = exit).grid(column=3, row = 3)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

# cleaning up/polishing
# winfo_children() gets all children of the object widget. ie gets all widgets included in mainframe
for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
feet_entry.focus()
#root.bind("<Return>", calculate)
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't know much about Jupyter notebooks but the `root.quit()` is useless as you have `root.destroy()` in there.

Comment: I initially only had the root.destroy() and encountered the problem so included root.quit() in case it had a different functionality, but the problem still existed.

Comment: The `root.destroy()` exits the `mainloop` and destroys all of the child widgets as well as the window. So there is no need for the `for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.destroy()` and the `root.quit()`. Also once the `mainloop` exists the program will end too so the `raise SystemExit` is useless too.

Comment: Again, the child.destroy() was an attempt to solve the the issue. I thought maybe a widget didn't quit properly and therefore was causing the issue. 

Made changes you mentioned above, you're right still works as planned, but the issues still persists. I'm thinking it might have something to do with Tkinter capturing keyboard input, but I'm new to Tkinter and not sure if that's something it does.

Comment: I've found part of the issue, the ttk.Button is causing the issue. If I change the buttons to normal tk.Button the issue no longer exists. I'm not sure if there is a way to fix the delay or if it's some underlying issue with the ttk widgets.

Comment: I rarely use `ttk` but I have looked at it's source code (the part that's written in python) and I still find this problem interesting because it shouldn't happen.